# how to test android.intent.action.SYNC

Tags: android

Does anybody know the working of `android.intent.action.SYNC`? How would one go about testing a `android.content.BroadcastReceiver` which waits for this event.

Wait unti it happes. If so, how often does it happen?

Send yourself a message with adb? If so, what do you send to make it realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACTION_SYNC is not used by anyone. I looked into entire Android repo and seems no one uses it. It is just defined in Intent.java.

I'm not sure why do you want to rely on this Intent. Please look below thread. Hope this helps.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dc7118e28c1fcaa

Comment: Is see. A no-op. Damm. Now I have to set up my own timer events to sync. And check that the sync setting is set to on. What a pain.